# How may I work around this corruption of sphere() output?

Tags: processing

How may I work around this corruption of sphere() output?

[image]

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); 
  translate(width/2, height/2);  
  strokeWeight(0);
  fill(color(255, 255, 255), 128);
  sphereDetail(10);sphere(100); // corrupt: http://i.imgur.com/1XmA8Om.png
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After a bunch of googling, here's what I discovered:

This isn't really a bug or a corruption, since it's exactly how OpenGL (and therefore Processing) was designed to behave. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/02/18/depth-sorting-alpha-blended-objects/) is an article that explains it much better than I can.

But basically, Processing is drawing a bunch of triangles in OpenGL to render the sphere for you. Since your sphere is transparent, Processing is drawing a ton of transparent triangles to the screen. This is problematic, since drawing order matters in this case. But by default Processing doesn't do any sorting of what it's drawing, so you end up with the artifacts you're seeing.

You can tell Processing to sort based on depth by enabling the depth sort hint inside your `setup()` function:

```
hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
```

With this addition, you have your beautiful gray sphere:

[image]

And you can even draw transparent shapes behind transparent shapes:

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); 
  translate(width/2, height/2);  

  strokeWeight(0);
  sphereDetail(10);

  fill(color(255, 255, 255), 128);
  sphere(100);

  translate(0, 0, -500);
  fill(color(255, 0, 0), 128);
  sphere(100);
}
```

[image]

Try this without enabling the depth sort hint, you won't be able to see the red sphere through the gray sphere!

However, note that enabling this feature will slow down rendering speed.

[Here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/90) is a GitHub issue discussing the addition of this feature. But this is not very well documented, so if anybody has any more information, I'll be happy to expand this answer.

Comment: Thanks. That suffers from the fault of apparently drawing the hidden back side of the sphere, hence that the pixel colour is 192x3 rather than 128x3 as specified by alpha. But it may be better than nothing.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Maybe I'm missing something, but seeing the back of the sphere seems correct to me. Think about a colored hollow glass sphere in real life: you see the front of the sphere, then through that you see the back of the sphere, then through that you see whatever is behind the sphere. You don't stop seeing the back of the sphere.

Comment: @Kevin "note that enabling this feature will slow down rendering speed." You're not kidding! On 64K objects, frame time went from ~0.5s to ~8s.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Yeah, this stuff can get pretty confusing. But bascially, OpenGL treats opaque stuff and transparent stuff differently. It would make sense to not draw the back of the sphere if it was opaque- no sense wasting time drawing stuff you won't see. But everything goes out the window when you have transparent objects. Then OpenGL's ability to not draw stuff that's behind other stuff actually hurts you. To fix this problem you have to draw everything in the correct order, which requires a bunch of overhead. So you might want to ask yourself whether you really need all the transparency.